# why is my code not accepting letters as user input

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

my code runs without errors or anything but after I put in an "F" or "P" it skips to "click any button to continue" but if I use any numbers it goes through the code fine.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // needed to use set precision

using namespace std;

void calcCost(double f_benefits, double F, double total_cost, double emp_salary)
{
    if (f_benefits == F)
        (total_cost += emp_salary * 1.5);
    else 
        (total_cost += emp_salary * 1.25);   // calculating operating function

}

int main()
{
    
    double num_emp = 0; // employees
    double emp_salary = 0; // employees salary
    double f_benefits = 0; // are they full time or part time benifits
    double total_cost = 0;
    int F = 0;
    int P = 0;

    cout << setw(69) << "Cost of Operation\n\n";

    cout << "Please enter the number of employees to process: ";
    cin >> num_emp;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num_emp; i++)  // loop for each employees salary and benifits
    {
        cout << "Please enter the salary for employee " << i << ":";
        cin >> emp_salary;
            
        cout << "Is employee " << i << " receiving(F)ull or (P)artial benefits ? Please enter F or P : "; // Dont forget input validation for this step
        cin >> f_benefits;
        
    }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double num_emp = 0; // employees` -- Why is the number of employees a floating point value?  Are you expecting 1.4523 employees, or 0.75 of a person working?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `f_benefits` be a string?

Comment: i am new so forgive me but when i tried it as a string it didn't work and wouldn't even let me access my code. so i had to change it back to a double

Answer (score 0):

The "cin >> f_benefits" is trying to read a double value. You should read the response into a char or string. Reading into a string expects a newline before returning.

You should also check that you got an "F" or "P" .

Comment: thank you for this i realized my "F" and "P" were the wrong data type.